# Navigation buttons stay / shift

Tags: css, navigation

I'm trying to get the last two navigation buttons ("Education" and "Contact") to move the social media icons to the left, and then stay there.

http://comms101.co.za/populus/index.php#

For some reason immediately when clicked, it momentarily displays correctly BUT then the social media icons revert back. If you click the button again, then it displays correctly (how it should display).

The navigation is a php include. Here is the code:

```
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5">
                    <div class="logo"><a href="#"><img src="imgs/logo.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 mn">
                    <div class="follow current1" style=""> <a href="#"><img src="imgs/f.png" alt=""></a> <a href="#"><img src="imgs/int.png" alt=""></a> <a href="#"><img src="imgs/in.png" alt=""></a> </div>
                    <div id="menu-icon">
                    <div class="menu-icn"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="menu" id="menu">
                    <ul id="links">
                        <li class="link"><a href="index.php">HOME</a></li>
                     <li class="link"><a href="about.php">ABOUT</a></li>
                     <li class="link"><a href="resources.php">RESOURCES</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a href="training.php">TRAINING</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a href="coaching.php">COACHING</a></li>
                        <li class="folow current1 current"><a href="education.php">EDUCATION</a></li>
                        <li class="folow1 current2 link"><a href="contact.php">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are adding an extra class to move social icons to left that one link2
"follow current1 link2".
so when you click then jquery add this class but on same time page refresh then "link2" class gone.
so what you need is to set the condition through php,
if the page is contact us then add class "link2" into this div.

```html
<div class="follow current1 link2"> 
  <a href="#"><img src="imgs/f.png" alt=""></a> 
  <a href="#"><img src="imgs/int.png" alt=""></a> 
  <a href="#"><img src="imgs/in.png" alt=""></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: my pleasure, will you please tick this answer to correct, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `.link1` class has to be here when you load education page for example.

A way to do this is to test the active current page and to add class with a PHP condition in the menu.

It displays momently good because of surely a JS script you made on click of the link and then it loads the page.